# Are there stats comparison but for badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

I love seeing my rankings compared to other members of the site here http://stackexchange.com/leagues/7/month/gaming/2017-03-01/

But I wonder, do the same ranking exist, but for badges? Like how do I rank in the number of gold badges compared to the other uses?

Tagged as discussion, but I guess it could also be a feature request, if this doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/650575/badge-rankings) that I made in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

It's a little crude, but it gets the job done. You can change the `@Class` variable to change which medal type you would like to see by entering the number you want to use below the SQL Window for the Class parameter.

- 1 is Gold
- 2 is Silver
- 3 is Bronze

The only thing I couldn't figure out was how to get the Ranking next to the rows.  You will have to manually count how far down on the list you are to see where you stand (I think you are in the top 50 for gold medals)!

Note that I believe the data in the Explorer is updated only once a week, so it could be off by some.

Answer (score 3):

There is no 'badge league', but you can still compare badges on an individual (badge or user) basis.

---

### Individual Badges

For starters, you can see how many of a particular badge has been awarded by clicking on the '[Badges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges)' Tab.

[image: Badges Page]

Clicking into a Badge from this page will then show you the breakdown of who has earned the badge (and when they earned it). For example, here's [Altruist](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/181/altruist):

---

### Individual Users

If you visit a user's profile, you can also see the breakdown of which badges they  have earned. Clicking on a Badge on a User Profile will then show the breakdown of the questions/answers of where it has been awarded (if relevant).

For example, here is [mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/28182/robotnik?tab=badges):

[image: User Profile Badge tab]

---

Those are the best ways to compare badges as they exist currently.

---

**Note:** While I'm sure you don't do this (and wouldn't dream of it), I think it's worth mentioning for future readers:

Earning rep/badges is fun, that's why they exist! But the best way to get both is to **contribute to the site in a genuine fashion**: Don't be the person begging for upvotes or spamming links to your posts (on or off-site) to generate views.

If you focus on the genuine quality of your contributions you'll find the badges and rep will flow naturally.